# PHP Filter to filter parsed RSS/XML

Tags: php, filter, xml-parsing, rss

I'm struggling getting a parsed rss feed to filter on a few values within the description.
Its a feed for traffic-information and i want to filter the feed to only display some roads instead of all.
So i need to filter the feed to ONLY show items that have roadnr "A2" or "A4" or "N15" and so on.

Here's my code so far (dont mind the table part :-) )

Any ideas that this noob can follow?
Thanks in advance!

Bonuspoints for a "No results" message if no items (empty list)...

```
<?php
           $ch = curl_init("https://www.verkeerplaza.nl/rssfeed");
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);  
           curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);  
           curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
           curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);  
           curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  

           $result=curl_exec ($ch);
           $data = strstr($result, '<?');  
           $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);  

 curl_close($curl);


$xml = simplexml_load_string($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
//die('<pre>' . print_r($xml], TRUE) . '</pre>');



$lastUpdate = $xml->channel->pubDate;

echo $lastUpdate;
echo "<table>";
echo "<tbody>";


for($i = 0; $i <5 ; $i++){
    
    $pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;
    $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
    $description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
    $enclosure = $xml->channel->item[$i]->enclosure['url'];

    echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>
            <img src='$enclosure' width='50'>
            </td>
            <td>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>";
      echo "<td>
        <b>$title</b><br/>
        <small>$pubDate</small><br/>
        $description<br/><br/>
            </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
  echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important changes you need to make are the addition of a way to filter the items based upon your list of roads, and changing your loop through the items so that it does not used a fixed number of iterations.

From there, we can make a number of small improvements to make the code mor readable and manageable. This is what I would consider a minimum viable solution. You could spend a lot of time making the templating and road matching more sophisticated, but this gets the job done, assuming that the road names always **begin with** your identifiable strings (A2, A4, N15, etc.)

```php
<?php
// Test data
$data = <<<END
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <title>Verkeerplaza.nl RSS feed</title>
        <link>https://www.verkeerplaza.nl</link>
        <description>Alle actuele files en verkeersinformatie van Verkeerplaza.nl</description>
        <atom:link href="https://www.verkeerplaza.nl/rssfeed" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
        <pubDate>2021-06-16T19:13:21+00:00</pubDate>
        <copyright>Copyright (c) 2019 -2021, Moop Mobility B.V.</copyright>
        <atom:logo>https://www.verkeerplaza.nl/favicon.png</atom:logo>
        <logo>https://www.verkeerplaza.nl/favicon.png</logo>
        <item>
            <title>A67 Eindhoven &gt; Venlo Tussen Afrit Asten en Brug Brug over de Zuid-Willemsvaart</title>
            <link>https://verkeerplaza.nl/files/A67</link>
            <pubDate>2021-06-16T21:12:00+02:00</pubDate>
            <description>Ongeluk tussen Afrit Asten en Brug Brug over de Zuid-Willemsvaart</description>
            <enclosure length="0" type="image/jpeg" url="https://verkeerplaza.nl/images/map-icons/red/01@3x.png"/>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>A2 Amsterdam &gt; Utrecht Tussen Afrit Ouderkerk aan de Amstel en Afrit Amsterdam-Zuidoost</title>
            <link>https://verkeerplaza.nl/files/A2</link>
            <pubDate>2021-06-16T21:43:42+02:00</pubDate>
            <description>Ongeluk tussen Afrit Ouderkerk aan de Amstel en Afrit Amsterdam-Zuidoost</description>
            <enclosure length="0" type="image/jpeg" url="https://verkeerplaza.nl/images/map-icons/red/01@3x.png"/>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>A3 Eindhoven &gt; Foo</title>
            <link>https://verkeerplaza.nl/files/A67</link>
            <pubDate>2021-06-16T21:12:10+02:00</pubDate>
            <description>Brug over de Zuid-Willemsvaart</description>
            <enclosure length="0" type="image/jpeg" url="https://verkeerplaza.nl/images/map-icons/red/01@3x.png"/>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
END;

// Load XML into SimpleXMLElement
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

/*
 * Define a template for our row markup, insert token strings for the values
 */
$rowTemplate = <<<END
<tr>
    <td><img src="%IMG%" width="50"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <b>%ROAD%</b><br/>
        <small>%DATE%</small><br/>
        %DESC%
        <br/><br/>
    </td>
</tr>
END;

// Create an array of the tokens used int ht template
$tokens = ['%IMG%', '%ROAD%', '%DATE%', '%DESC%'];

// Create an array of valid road names
$targetRoads = ['A67', 'A2'];

// String buffer for the row markup
$rowMarkup = '';
foreach($xml->channel->item as $currItem)
{
    /*
     * Create an array of the values form the item that should be used
     * to replace tokens in the row template. This approach requires
     * the order of the values in this array to match the order of tokens
     * in the $tokens array. We can think about enhancing the later, but
     * it works for now.
     */
    $values = [
        $currItem->enclosure['url'],
        $currItem->title,
        $currItem->pubDate,
        $currItem->description
    ];

    // Create a flag to indicate whether or not the current item should be output as a row
    $valid = false;

    // Loop through the target road values
    foreach($targetRoads as $currRoad)
    {
        /*
         * The target road values are strings that should appear at the beginning
         * of the item title. The format of the feed is expected to consistently
         * include these strings at the beginning of each title.
         *
         * Look for the string at the beginning of the title, followed by a
         * whitespace character. This way, target "A2" returns "A2 Amsterdam"
         * but not "A25 Amsterdam"
         */
        preg_match("/^$currRoad\s/", $currItem->title, $matches);

        // If $matches is not empty, we have a good hit
        if(!empty($matches))
        {
            // Set the valid flag and break out of the search loop.
            $valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If the current item contains a road we are interested in, output a row
    if($valid)
    {
        // Use simple string replacement to generate markup from the row template
        $rowMarkup .= str_replace($tokens, $values, $rowTemplate);
    }
}

// Row to display in the table if no results are found.
$noResultsRow = <<<END
<tr>
    <td>No results</td>
</tr>
END;

// If we have no results, assign the value of $noResultsRow the $rowMarkup var
$rowMarkup = (empty($rowMarkup)) ? $noResultsRow:$rowMarkup;

// Format the pub date of the feed into something pretty
$lastUpdate = $xml->channel->pubDate;
$formattedDate = date('F j, Y g:i A', strtotime($lastUpdate));

// Create the final markup
$output = <<<END
<p>Last update: $formattedDate</p>
<table>
    <tbody>
        $rowMarkup
    </tbody>
</table>
END;

echo $output.PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Wow, that indeed is another aproach and works perfect! Bonuspoints earned ;-)

Thanks!